# Insert String from Array after X amount of characters (Outside HTML) in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, character

I've looked and can't find a solution to this feature we would like to write.  I'm fairly new to PHP so any help, advice and code examples are always greatly appreciated.

Let me explain what we want to do...

We have a block of HTML inside a string - the content could be up to 2000 words with styling such as `<p>`, `<ul>`, `<h2>` included in this HTML content string.

We also have an array of images related to this content inside a separate string.

We need to add the images from the array string into the HTML content at equal spaces without breaking the HTML code.  So a simple character count won't work as it could break the HTML tags.

We need to equally space the images.  So, for example; if we had 2000 words inside the HTML content string and 10 images in the array, we need to place an image every 200 words.

Any help or coding samples provided in order to achieve this is greatly appreciated - thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$numword =  str_word_count($str, 0);
```

for getting the number of row

or

```
$array = str_word_count($str,1);
```

for getting in $array an array with all the word (one for index) and then iterating on  this array for rebuild text you need adding every number of time (word)  the code for your image

> This Sample is form php Manual
>
> ```
> <?php
>
>   $str = "Hello fri3nd, you're
>        looking          good today!";
>
>   print_r(str_word_count($str, 1));
>   print_r(str_word_count($str, 2));
>   print_r(str_word_count($str, 1, 'àáãç3'));
>
>   echo str_word_count($str);
>
> ?>
> ```

this is related result

> ```
> Array
>     (
>         [0] => Hello
>         [1] => fri
>         [2] => nd
>         [3] => you're
>         [4] => looking
>         [5] => good
>         [6] => today
>     )
>
>     Array
>     (
>         [0] => Hello
>         [6] => fri
>         [10] => nd
>         [14] => you're
>         [29] => looking
>         [46] => good
>         [51] => today
>     )
>
>     Array
>     (
>         [0] => Hello
>         [1] => fri3nd
>         [2] => you're
>         [3] => looking
>         [4] => good
>         [5] => today
>     )
>
>     7
> ```

You can find it in [this doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

for the insert you can try this way

```
$num = 200;  // number of word after which  inert the image
$text = $array[0]; // initialize the text with the first word in array

for ($cnt =1; $cnt< count( $array); $cnt++){
   $text .= $array[$cnt];  // adding the word to the text 
   if (($cnt % $num) == 0) {   // if  array index multiple fo 200 insert the image
    $text .= "<img src='your_img_path' >";
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how can we insert the images from the array into the HTML string at the desired locations?

Comment: I have update the answer and if the answer is useful please rate it and/or mark as accepted...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Will this not break the HTML in the code?  Will it count HTML tags as words?  We have <li> items with lengthy paragraphs in them.  We don't want to insert the images in <p> -  The inserts need to be completely outside any HTML tags.

Comment: Perhaps using some DOM functions will work?  It would need to close <ul> tags correctly too I suppose so it can insert the image.

Comment: The block is HTML/XML like ? Could you post/show  a sample  editing your question?....